How to upgrade the existing container registry from basic to premium?
Bicep Code for ACR provisioning:
resource containerRegistry 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2023-07-01' = {
  name: 'acrprccivivek01'
  location: 'centralindia'
  sku: {
    name: 'Basic'
  }
}

Deployment Code and Result:
PS C:\Windows\System32> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name 'BasciACRDeployment' -TemplateFile 'D:\LearnBicep\storageAcc.bicep' -ResourceGroupName 'vivekchak-rg' -Mode Incremental

DeploymentName          : BasciACRDeployment
ResourceGroupName       : vivekchak-rg
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 12/27/2024 7:46:43 AM
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            :
Parameters              :
Outputs                 :
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :

we have deployed the basic azure container registry using above bicep and observed that it is not having networking features.
Can we upgrade the ACR from basic to premium using the same bicep template or not possible?
I just want to ask the experts here before trying on my project subscription.

Are you getting an error while upgrading the SKU from Basic to Premium?

To upgrade the ACR from Basic to Premium, you can use the same template by changing Basic to Premium, Here is my result


Can we upgrade the ACR from basic to premium using the same bicep template or not possible?

Yes, you can upgrade the ACR from Basic to Premium by using the same template and changing Basic to Premium

Note: Make sure to take a backup of the ACR images before upgrading

    resource containerRegistry 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2023-07-01' = {
      name: 'acrprccivivek01'
      location: 'centralindia'
      sku: {
        name: 'Premium'
      }
    }

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name  'BasciACRDeployment' -TemplateFile  '/home/user/Acr.bicep' -ResourceGroupName  'Automation_RG'

After running the code, the container registry has been upgraded to Premium successfully


When we upgrade, will we loose any repositories (data) uploaded to ACR?

There is no registry downtime or impact on registry operations when you move between service tiers. Chekc the MS link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-skus#changing-tiers for more details

What is wrong in my question that I got 3 downvotes? Am I asked in wrong forum or wrong question?

You haven't specified any error that you are getting during the upgrade

I believe i have mentioned a line on the end of the question description that I want to ask experts here before trying and losing the data or getting an error.

Should I delete the question in that case or how do I get the upvotes to make my question and your answer as valid @VenkatV.

You unaccepted my answer.

then how do I get rid of all the downvotes on my question if it is a valid because I clearly mentioned a line on the end of the question description that I want to ask experts here before trying and losing the data or getting an error.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thanks, I have accepted your answer before the upvoting because my main issue is the azure doubt so it is solved. Thanks
